# Execute javascript in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, javascript, html, dom

I am trying to resolve the links in a google search results list by executing a javascript on the page that would normally resolve when you click the link. Basically, I am trying to resolve all of them when the page loads.

Here is the html generated by google of the first two search results:

```
<H2 class=hd>Search Results</H2>
<DIV id=ires>
<OL id=rso eid="3gHFUYToG6LD0gGJ2IDAAQ">
<LI class=g>
<DIV class=rc data-hveid="43"><SPAN style="FLOAT: left"></SPAN>
<H3 class=r><A onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNH7JvhrnBRwX-7DKsGJZoasX9zqFA','','0CCwQFjAA','','',event)" href="http://prezi.com/wnx5jat2oene/ipad/">IPad by <EM>Frunk La Je</EM> on Prezi</A></H3>
<DIV class=s>
<DIV>
<DIV style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" class="f kv"><CITE>prezi.com/wnx5jat2oene/ipad/</CITE>‎
<DIV class="action-menu ab_ctl"><A aria-haspopup=true aria-expanded=false id=am-b0 class="clickable-dropdown-arrow ab_button" role=button href="#" jsaction="ab.tdd; keydown:ab.hbke; keypress:ab.mskpe" data-ved="0CC0Q7B0wAA" aria-label="Result details"><SPAN class=mn-dwn-arw></SPAN></A>
<DIV class="action-menu-panel ab_dropdown" role=menu tabIndex=-1 jsaction="keydown:ab.hdke; mouseover:ab.hdhne; mouseout:ab.hdhue" data-ved="0CC4QqR8wAA">
<UL>
<LI class="action-menu-item ab_dropdownitem" role=menuitem><A class=fl onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNHsvjmPpYAOeqVOHIIs_PWPuD5JaQ','','0CC8QIDAA','','',event)" href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:bKCj-2ogWdIJ:prezi.com/wnx5jat2oene/ipad/+frunk+la+je&amp;cd=1&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk&amp;gl=us">Cached</A></LI></UL></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV class="f slp"></DIV><SPAN class=st>IPad. No description. by <EM>Frunk La Je</EM> on 7 June 2012 4 Tweet <B>...</B> thanks&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;. Make a copy Share Embed Like. by <EM>Frunk La Je</EM> on 7 June 2012 4.</SPAN></DIV></DIV></DIV></LI>
<LI class=g>
<DIV class=rc data-hveid="48"><SPAN style="FLOAT: left"></SPAN>
<H3 class=r><A onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNE7-nvy-ymTrBI0x4zleJOUXlY6nA','','0CDEQFjAB','','',event)" href="http://prezi.com/user/q53evqg1dnrn/"><EM>Frunk La Je</EM> on Prezi</A></H3>
<DIV class=s>
```

The function that resolves the first link:

```
onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNH7JvhrnBRwX-7DKsGJZoasX9zqFA','','0CCwQFjAA','','',event)"
```

I tried this:

```
    foreach (HtmlElement h in web.Document.All)
    {
        h.RaiseEvent("onmousedown");
    }
```

I tried replacing "onmousedown" with "MouseDown".

I tried this too:

```
web.Document.InvokeScript("rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNH7JvhrnBRwX-7DKsGJZoasX9zqFA','','0CCwQFjAA','','',event)");
```

Any ideas how I can get this function to execute? I've also looked at the getElementByID function, but I don't know what the ID is for this.

Comment: Also, don't think I'm being stupid and not seeing that the links are right there in the html code. Those aren't the links I want. I want the links that google generates.

Comment: The html that you've shown is from Google search you say? or you are the one that generates it? Have you tried onclick instead of onmousedown in your HTML? By the way ID is to target specific element in your HTML, so which means you could focus on one tag/element that you want to work on.

Comment: It's the code generated by google. I don't see how replacing onmousedown with onclick is going to help. I need it to execute the function automatically without any intervention.

Comment: Have you tried simulating a mouse click programmatically on the link?

Comment: I have not. I don't know how I would do it without actually programming the mouse cursor to move and click the link, which is not very user friendly.

Comment: you can simulate a click, check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try to **simulate a click** programmatically, let's say in one of your `anchor tag <a>`. Now using your own code we will simulate a click on your `first anchor tag` which is `subscript 0` (as shown below), like this:

```
 HtmlElement simulateClickAnchor = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")[0];
 simulateClickAnchor.InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: @Synaps3 Have you tried changing click to onlick, that is, simulateClickAnchor.InvokeMember("onclick");

Answer (score 1):

```
HtmlDocument doc = browser.Document;
HtmlElement head = doc.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement s = doc.CreateElement("script");
s.SetAttribute("text","function sayhello() { alert('hello'); }");
head.AppendChild(s);
browser.Document.InvokeScript("sayHello");
```

Comment: This has been working for me quite well.  Thank you.